# No traceback when app crashes or has errors

Tags: heroku, flask, gunicorn, error-logging

I have a small Python web app that I set up using [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python). Everything seems to be running smoothly, but when the program crashes or encounters an error, I am not getting a backtrace or error message. I am using

```
heroku logs --tail
```

to view the server logs in real time.

For example, I introduce a "list index out of range" error with this code:

```
thing = [1, 2, 3]
print thing[4]
```

I’m definitely hitting that code, because I am logging a message to the console on the previous line. But in the Heroku logs, I see my log message, and then nothing. No indication of an error or failure. How can I see my logs? Am I supposed to be looking in a different place?

If I run the same code in the Python 2.7.6 interactive interpreter, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zev, here is a simple Flask app that dumps a stack trace into the Heroku logs:

https://github.com/jwatson/simple-flask-stacktrace

Hopefully you can figure out what's different between your app and this. The pains I take to set up the standard logger don't seem to make any difference, so I'm not quite sure what's stopping your app from complaining loudly on exceptions. I am using Gunicorn as my WSGI server, but that doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: Are you saying that one has to configure logging as a prerequisite to getting stack traces? Is the default to fail silently?

Comment: All I had to do was `app.debug = True`. I didn’t see that anywhere else I had looked. Thanks!

Comment: @Zev Yeah that one got me too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555038/. The right answer is indeed `app.debug = True`. BTW SO lets you answer your own question and still get points when people vote for it... You can even accept your own answer if it's better (as in this case).

Comment: @Zev Another alternative (if you want to give jwatson some credit here, since he was helpful indeed) is to propose an edit to his answer, with your `app.debug = True` comment added. If rejected though, don't repeat, or you'll hear from moderators. (I wish SO would instead just display your previous rejection info in that case... sigh)